# How to pipe two input and output file object in python just like java.io.PipedInputStream in java?

Tags: java, python

I want to use tar to archive a local folder and upload to S3. I don't like having a temporary tar file in the local file system because the tar file will be huge.

I want to have a way to pipe the two file-like objects: tar write file-like object and S3 read file-like object, just like `java.io.PipedInputStream` in Java.

Comment: Why? These streams are just toys in Java. Not of much practical use. I used them once briefly 22 years ago and quickly changed them to a `Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import threading
import time

in_pipe, out_pipe = os.pipe()
out_file = os.fdopen(out_pipe, 'wb')
def worker():
    for i in range(6):
        out_file.write(str.encode('Test text...\n'))
        time.sleep(1)
        out_file.flush()

t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[])
t.start()
in_file = os.fdopen(in_pipe, 'rb')
for line_ in in_file:
    print(line_)

time.sleep(1)
t.join()
```